# Increment variable Javascript since a date

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to use 3 different counters that show me 3 different increasing numbers starting from a certain date. I've tryed this:

```
<script>
  var START_DATE_1 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
  var INTERVAL_1 = 5; // in seconds
  var INCREMENT_1 = 1; // increase per tick
  var START_VALUE_1 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
  var count_1 = 0;

  window.onload = function()
  {
    var msInterval_1 = INTERVAL_1 * 1000;
    var now_1 = new Date();
    count_1 = parseInt((now_1 - START_DATE_1)/msInterval_1) * INCREMENT_1 + START_VALUE_1;
    document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;
    setInterval("count_1 += INCREMENT_1; document.getElementById('counter_1').innerHTML = count_1;", msInterval_1);
  }
</script>

<script>
  var START_DATE_2 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
  var INTERVAL_2 = 5; // in seconds
  var INCREMENT_2 = 1; // increase per tick
  var START_VALUE_2 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
  var count_2 = 0;

  window.onload = function()
  {
    var msInterval_2 = INTERVAL_2 * 1000;
    var now_2 = new Date();
    count_2 = parseInt((now_2 - START_DATE_2)/msInterval_2) * INCREMENT_2 + START_VALUE_2;
    document.getElementById('counter_2').innerHTML = count_2;
    setInterval("count_2 += INCREMENT_2; document.getElementById('counter_2').innerHTML = count_2;", msInterval_2);
  }
</script>

<script>
  var START_DATE_3 = new Date("July 18, 2016 10:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
  var INTERVAL_3 = 5; // in seconds
  var INCREMENT_3 = 1; // increase per tick
  var START_VALUE_3 = 0; // initial value when it's the start date
  var count_3 = 0;

  window.onload = function()
  {
    var msInterval_3 = INTERVAL_3 * 1000;
    var now_3 = new Date();
    count_2 = parseInt((now_3 - START_DATE_3)/msInterval_3) * INCREMENT_3 + START_VALUE_3;
    document.getElementById('counter_3').innerHTML = count_2;
    setInterval("count_3 += INCREMENT_3; document.getElementById('counter_3').innerHTML = count_3;", msInterval_3);
  }
</script>

<div id="counter_1"></div>
<div id="counter_2"></div>
<div id="counter_3"></div>
```

This doesn't work as expected and only the 3td div is populated but now working as expected too (as soon as I load the page it show me a number then after few seconds restart from 1).

What's wrong? How should I do it without using JQuery also?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a code analysis - this would be something for [SE-CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (highly recommended to post there too once you got it working), but your error is, that you are assigning something to a function more than once - hence, only the last assignment is actually called `onload`.

So -- you are assigning `window.onload = function()` in your first `<script>` tag, then you are **overriding** it in your second; and you're **overriding** the second assignment again in your third `<script>` tag.

You can't do that if you want to assign all 3 functions to a single (`onload`) event.

---

If you want to add multiple listeners for a single event, use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {});
```

Now inside that function, you can add all your code that you want to have executed `onload` of your page; in addition to the code you wanted to have executed onload in another function!

Here's a simple demonstration using the same techniques as described above, but with click listeners. Notice the first function will never be called.

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {
  alert("I will never alert, because of the next function");
}
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {
  alert("I will alert, because I'm not overriden");
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("I will alert too");
});

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("And a third alert. Disturbing");
});
```

```html
<div id="a">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I've tryed your suggestion without success anyway.